# Excel - How to Delete all rows in which cell B is empty in a data set

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Excel - How to Delete all rows in which cell B is empty in a data set

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the data in the worksheet by Column B. The empty cells will either be at the bottom of the sort or the top of the sort. Highlight the row numbers starting from the first empty cell and take it to the bottom. Press the Delete key on the keyboard. Voila!